# How Print html5 canvas with it parent div

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

My web page has a canvas inside div. i need to print this div with canvas using javascript .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osyZd.png)

Comment: See http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your canvas to a normal image to achieve this.

Get the data URI containing a representation of the image using the `canvas.toDataURL` like this,

```
var canvasObj = document.getElementById("yourCanvasId");
var imgObj    = canvasObj.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Then you can write the image object as,

```
document.write('<img src="'+imgObj+'"/>');
```

This will work fine while taking the printouts.

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 0):

You can [html2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) it gives you a png of the visible part of your Website. You can try it via browser console.